# SQL Query that only shows dates in the given weeknumber

Tags: php, sql

I have a question regarding SQL and PHP. I have made the following table that saves records of a timesheet. The attribute `uur_datum` saves the date like 2015-03-18. This date is in week 12.

I need a SQL query that shows only the dates within a given week. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT dates WHERE week = 12;
```

I could add a attribute named week and save the weeknumber, but I am sure there bust be a more effective way to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sys_uren` (
  `uur_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uur_datum` date NOT NULL,
  `start_tijd` time NOT NULL,
  `eind_tijd` time NOT NULL,
  `uurcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `akkoord` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uur_id`),
  KEY `uurcode_id` (`uurcode`)
)
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: Although it looks like MySQL, you should specify what database you are using.

Comment: I figured as much, have you checked the link to the `WEEK()` function? That should make it easy to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Weeks are funny things. Some places start each week on Sunday; others use Monday. Rules for determining the dates in the first week of the year vary.

MySQL has some convenience functions for dealing with weeks. You need to pick the right one. You need to use it carefully, because your query has to do the Right Thing at the beginnings and endings of each year.

The right function isn't `week()`, `weekofyear()`, or `datepart()`. The right function is `yearweek()`.

```
create table test(test_date date not null);
insert into test values ('2013-12-31'), ('2014-01-10'), ('2015-01-10');

select 
    test_date, 
    year(test_date) as yr, 
    week(test_date, 3) as wk, 
    yearweek(test_date, 3) as yr_wk
from test
order by test_date;
```

[Mode 3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) corresponds to ISO weeks, which is what I use.

```
test_date   yr    wk  yr_wk
--
2013-12-31  2013  1   201401
2014-01-10  2014  2   201402
2015-01-10  2015  2   201502
```

Look at the first row. No matter how you calculate weeks, '2013-12-31' simply can *not* be in the first week of 2013, right? But it *can* be in the first week of 2014. (It is, according to ISO.)

So you need to use the expression `yearweek(your_column, correct_mode_number)` to get the right week value for your dates. The mode you use is application-dependent.

```
select *
from sys_uren
where yearweek(uur_datum, 3) = 201512;
```

I used mode 3 here, but you might need a different one. See the documentation I linked above.

---

**Week modes**

Modes 1, 3, 5, and 7 all mean that Monday is the first day of the week. They differ in range and in how they define the first week of the year.

Comment: So... I need mode 5 if I want to start the week on Monday?

Comment: Modes 1, 3, 5, and 7 all mean the week starts on Monday. The difference is in how they determine the first week of the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of weeks included between 2 different dates in mySQL using functions DATEDIFF() and CEIL() as below :

```
SELECT CEIL( DATEDIFF('2011-05-10','2011-05-2')/7 ) AS Weeks;
```

Additional Query :

```
SELECT uur_datum from sys_uren WHERE  WEEKOFYEAR(uur_datum) = 12
```

Comment: I don't want to calculate the number of weeks, I want to return the dates within a weeknumber.

Comment: WEEKOFYEAR can seem useful. I added another query

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT `uur_datum` FROM `sys_uren` WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(uur_datum) LIKE 11;
```

This seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEPART

```
SELECT *
FROM sys_uren
WHERE DATEPART(week, uur_datum) = 12
```

Comment: I don't think that SQL Server uses backticks to escape table- and column names.

Comment: @jeroen Lets see what his actual db he using first, as i imagine your right and its now just SQLSERVER